# Add multiple pictureBox objects to a list using a loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, foreach

I have many `pictureBox` objects and I need to add them to a list.

I have tried this:

```
List<PictureBox> Pb = new List<PictureBox>();
for (int i=0; i<=7; i++)
{
    Pb.Add(pictureBox + "i");
}
```

How can I iterate over these objects?

Comment: There's not enough information here to understand what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i=0; i<=7; i++)
    Pb.Add((PictureBox)Controls.Find("pictureBox" +i, true)[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<PictureBox> Pb = this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything what is missing in your code is definition of `PictureBox`.

You should write something like this:

```
List<PictureBox> Pb = new List<PictureBox>();
for (int i=0; i<=7; i++)
{
    Pb.Add(new PictureBox()
    {
        // declare properties here
    });
}
```